# How to implement summary rows(Total rows) in WPF data-grid via MVVM

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, row, summary

I need a help to to make a summary row or total a row in WPF datagrid using MVVM pattern, special of this summary row is having a value for each column like a image shows below.First total calculation base on first 3 items and those are in one group.I couldn't find a good example or sample code for this issue.

Please refer this image:

[image]

Comment: are you using wpf basic datagrid ? or soething else ?

Comment: Put image directly in question

Comment: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/mrochon/archive/2009/10/16/displaying-hierarchical-data-in-the-datagrid.aspx , This is the only solution find out for my question. Anybody knows how to do it in WPF Desktop version?

Answer (score 0):

you can add a footer row to your datagrid like [This](http://thibaud60.blogspot.co.uk/2008/10/wpftoolkit-datagrid-with-footer-and.html) or like [This](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vinsibal/archive/2008/10/31/wpf-datagrid-frozen-row-sample.aspx)

-- updated --

if you need row Grouping have a look [Here](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/dpatra/grouping-in-datagrid-in-wpf/).. try to understand the concept of grouping and adding row group headers

Comment: Thank you for the reply, That's not exactly I need. http://i.imgur.com/G1NjqqR.jpg - According to the image, there is two type of rows one is act like parent(Total) for other rows.But both rows in same grid view and I'm using basic WPF data-grid.

Comment: I have updated ans, have a look and let me know If you get any issue.

Comment: I try this link before. problem is not grouping rows , In my grid (http://i.imgur.com/G1NjqqR.jpg),you can see group header(Total rows) also have same type of column values which other rows had.

Answer (score 0):

Several solutions are possible. There is not enough detail in your explanations to select the most appropriate option.

Below is an example using the converter for summarizing by group and styling the group in the DataGrid.

```
namespace TotalRows
{
    public class ItemClass
    {
        public int Group { get; set; }
        public string Title { get; set; }

        public int Y2013 { get; set; }
        public int Y2014 { get; set; }
        public int Y2015 { get; set; }
        public int Y2016 { get; set; }
    }

}
```

```
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.Linq;

namespace TotalRows
{
    public class ExampleData
    {
        public static ObservableCollection<ItemClass> Items { get; }
            = new ObservableCollection<ItemClass>()
            {
                new ItemClass() {Group=1, Title="Item1", Y2013=1200, Y2014=1500, Y2015=1800, Y2016=1500},
                new ItemClass() {Group=1, Title="Item2", Y2013=2350, Y2014=2000, Y2015=2400, Y2016=2300},
                new ItemClass() {Group=1, Title="Item3", Y2013=4000, Y2014=4350, Y2015=5000, Y2016=5500},
                new ItemClass() {Group=2, Title="Item1", Y2013=1250, Y2014=1400, Y2015=1900, Y2016=1500},
                new ItemClass() {Group=2, Title="Item2", Y2013=1350, Y2014=2500, Y2015=2450, Y2016=2700},
                new ItemClass() {Group=2, Title="Item3", Y2013=3500, Y2014=3350, Y2015=5000, Y2016=5500},
            };
    }

}
```

```
using System;
using System.Globalization;
using System.Linq;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Markup;

namespace TotalRows
{
    public class TotalItemsConverter : IValueConverter
    {
        public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            if (value is CollectionViewGroup group)
            {
                switch (parameter)
                {
                    case "13": return group.Items.OfType<ItemClass>().Sum(item => item.Y2013);
                    case "14": return group.Items.OfType<ItemClass>().Sum(item => item.Y2014);
                    case "15": return group.Items.OfType<ItemClass>().Sum(item => item.Y2015);
                    case "16": return group.Items.OfType<ItemClass>().Sum(item => item.Y2016);
                }
            }

            return DependencyProperty.UnsetValue;
        }

        public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        public static TotalItemsConverter Instance { get; } = new TotalItemsConverter();
    }

    public class TotalItemsConverterExtension : MarkupExtension
    {
        public override object ProvideValue(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
            => TotalItemsConverter.Instance;
    }

}
```

```
<Window x:Class="TotalRows.TotalRowsWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:TotalRows"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="RowsTotalWindow" Height="450" Width="800">
    <FrameworkElement.Resources>
        <CollectionViewSource x:Key="items" Source="{x:Static local:ExampleData.Items}">
            <CollectionViewSource.GroupDescriptions>
                <PropertyGroupDescription PropertyName="Group"/>
            </CollectionViewSource.GroupDescriptions>
        </CollectionViewSource>
    </FrameworkElement.Resources>
    <Grid>
        <DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Mode=OneWay, Source={StaticResource items}}">
            <DataGrid.GroupStyle>
                <GroupStyle>
                    <GroupStyle.HeaderTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Converter={local:TotalItemsConverter}, ConverterParameter=13}" Margin="95,0,0,0"/>
                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Converter={local:TotalItemsConverter}, ConverterParameter=14}" Margin="15,0,0,0"/>
                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Converter={local:TotalItemsConverter}, ConverterParameter=15}" Margin="15,0,0,0"/>
                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Converter={local:TotalItemsConverter}, ConverterParameter=16}" Margin="15,0,0,0"/>
                            </StackPanel>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </GroupStyle.HeaderTemplate>
                </GroupStyle>
            </DataGrid.GroupStyle>
        </DataGrid>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```